# Does DKIM also sign the attachments, or only header fields and body?

Tags: email, security, spam, dkim

Does **DKIM** also sign the attachments? Or does it only header fields and body? If it signs attachments, can I configure that in some way in Thunderbird, in order to do it or not?

Comment: Thunderbird does not control DKIM. That's your outbound SMTP server. DKIM can (but doesn't have to) sign the message body from an RFC 5322 standpoint (basically: everything after the headers), which includes MIME containers when present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see [section 3.7 of the DKIM RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6376#section-3.7):

> With the exception of the canonicalization procedure described in
> Section 3.4, the DKIM signing process treats the body of messages as
> simply a string of octets.  DKIM messages MAY be either in plain-text
> or in MIME format; no special treatment is afforded to MIME content.
> **Message attachments** in MIME format MUST be included in the content
> that is signed.